# JSON через AJAX с HTML-кодом

Tags: php, ajax, json

через ajax обращаюсь к пхп-скрипту в результате получаю массив

```js
{
  "statuse": "1.3",
  "status_text": "success",
  "html_text": "<div id=\'close_popup\'></div>
   <div class=\'tbl\' id=\'user_work_tbl\'>
   Работы пользователя<table id=\'work_table\' border=1>
    <tr><td>
      Номер
     </td><td>
      Название
     </td><td>
      Описание
     </td>
    </tr><tr><td onClick=\'document.location=\'9' title=\'Щелкните чтобы открыть эту работу\'
      style=\'background: rgb(137, 137, 223);cursor:pointer;\'>
       1
      </td><td>
       333
      </td><td>
       3333
      </td>
     </tr></table></div>"
}
```

как видно тут вставлен кусок html-кода.
код ajax

```js
function loadList() {
    var JsonData = "load_list=true&login=<?php echo $_SESSION['login'];?>";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: JsonData,
      url: "text1.php",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      error: function(msg) {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert(obj);
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(msg);
        obj = JSON.parse(obj);
        var html_text = obj.html_text;
        $("#in_popup").text(html_text);
      },
    });
```

в результате уходит в error,а в alert выдает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сервер почему то сам делает ответ и отправляет мой json в своем, но если обратиться к скрипту через браузер то выдает мой нормальный json. в чем прикол,кто может пояснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "text1.php",
  data: { 
           load_list:true,
           login: "<?php echo $_SESSION['login'];?>",
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function(error, xhr, status) {
    console.log(error, xhr, status);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $("#in_popup").html(response.html_text);
  },
});
```

- скорее всего надо использовать метод GET
- немного рефакторинга. Пробуйте

Comment: А можно посмотреть сам php скрипт?

Comment: я решил передавать в json массив нужных данных(имя,айди,описание)и уже на стороне клиента формировать таблицу и выводить.